# Как отключить скролл страницы при клике на пробел

Tags: javascript, прокрутка, клавиатура

Хочу убрать скролл страницы при нажатии на пробел. Пробовал `preventDefault()` - не сработал.
Далее захотел исправить это так:

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
 if (e.keyCode === 32) {
   document.documentElement.scrollIntoView({
     block: 'start'
   });
 }
});
```

Но это работало некорректно, хотел бы понять, как можно это исправить

Comment: Один из первых линков в гугле: https://thewebdev.info/2021/07/30/how-to-prevent-the-pressing-of-the-space-bar-from-scrolling-the-page-with-javascript/

я скопировал код, открыл консоль браузера, запихнул туда и сработало, может есть смысл в вопросе показать проблему (нерабочий вариант) с `preventDefault`

Comment: Да, сработало, спасибо за решение

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как мы уже выяснили в комментариях `preventDefault` в этом же обработчике всё-таки успешно останавливает скролл и является решением проблемы:

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {  
  if (e.keyCode === 32 && e.target === document.body) {  
    e.preventDefault();  
  }  
});
```

Поскольку метод `preventDefault` предотвращает (отменяет) дефолтное действие, заданное браузером, то необходимо проверять, в контексте какого элемента он вызывается (`e.target === document.body`), иначе бы и предотвращалось написание пробелов в тексте в таких элементах как `input`, `textarea`.